# What does [ABC] mean inside a text?

Tags: parenthesis

I saw it many times in many texts. There will be a word or a phrase inside a text and surrounded by square brackets.

Examples:

> - This is **[the]** main purpose of xxx.
> - And it was called **[xxx]**.

There are many examples out there. What does it mean when you surround a text in square bracket inside a whole text?

Comment: Different style guides will have different positions regarding square brackets - some may specifically identify **[sic]** as a context that should use square rather than round brackets, for example. Or when quoting otherwise verbatim text, you might put square brackets around some non-verbatim element that you've re-worded for clarity in context. Plus there's a long-established convention in software / technical documentation that we may use them to delineate **[optional words]**.  In short, there are too many possibilities to list here, and your "examples" aren't valid or useful.

Comment: Check out [this style guide](https://writingcommons.org/article/inserting-or-altering-words-in-a-direct-quotation/) on the use of square brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\[I\]t literally scared her to death" - Why is "I" in brackets?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86053/it-literally-scared-her-to-death-why-is-i-in-brackets)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Square brackets](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/brackets.html) are mainly used to enclose additional information that was **not** actually said by the speaker. For example, if somebody says

> He shouldn't be allowed to get away with this

A reporter might decide that it is not clear who **He** refers to, and add the name in square brackets:

> He [John Doe] shouldn't be allowed to get away with this

It could be used to correct grammatical errors in the original speaker's text, as in your first example, But your second example certainly isn't a valid use of square brackets, because the contents of the brackets is fundamental to the sentence, not additional information.

Comment: @TypeIA yes, sic is related, but it is used to mark a grammatical or typographic error as coming from the original source. It would not be much help in indicating an omitted word, as in the first example.

Comment: The second example is sometimes used when the quote has been edited. For example the original speaker may have given several different names for the thing and explained why most of them were inaccurate, but the reported text just contains the correct name in. Or the original quote may have given the name in a different language, which is irrelevant in the reported quote.

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes, I know what it means. It's something that often appears in square brackets though and is neither source material nor editorial insertion. Also I wonder why my comment was deleted?

Comment: I could see the second example if the original sentence was something like "And it was called the same thing."  You'd put in the name/title in square brackets if your quote didn't include the earlier reference.

Comment: @JavaLatte I've removed my previous comment, because you (and the link) are correct. I must have been getting mixed up with the use of square brackets to swap capitalized letters (the "[T]his study has been widely cited" example in your link).

Comment: @alephzero I think more often or not the changes are actually for grammatical purposes when a quote has been integrated directly into a paragraph.

Comment: I think the more common example is when someone quotes a part of a long sentence, which does not have correct grammer because of missing words from the start/end of the sentence and fixes it by inserting a word, that makes it a correct short sentence.

Comment: Maybe you find an example for such an sentence. In fact when you swap your example it can be such an case, e.g., when an reporter wrote about John Doe and then quotes the sentence replacing `John Doe` with `he`.